# Having difficulty with a search and follow, using twitter gem and ruby

Tags: ruby, twitter, twitter-gem

So in PHP, this code works live, done months ago.

```
$tweetsToSlippy = $connection->get('http://search.twitter.com/search.json', array('q' => $query, 'since_id' => $since_id))->results;
foreach ($tweetsToSlippy as $tweet) 
{
    $user_id = $tweet->from_user;
    echo "adding $user_id <br>\n";
    $connection->post('friendships/create', array('screen_name' => $user_id));  
}
```

I am trying to do the same with Ruby. I can reply, I can update, but I lack the understanding of trying to accomplish what I did in the above code, which makes an API call and retrieves Json list and then pulls users from it.

```
def searchAdd
    topics = ['topic1', 'topic2']
    userBank = []
    topics.each do |topic|
        userBank << Twitter.search(topic, :result_type => "recent")
    end
    userBank.each do |user|
    Twitter.follow(user)
        puts user
    end
end
```

I'm lost, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Twitter.search.results` does not return `Twitter::User` objects, it returns `Twitter::Status` objects.

If I was trying to implement what you appear to be trying to implement, I would write it like this:

```
require 'twitter'

def search_add
  topics = ['peanut butter', 'jelly']
  search_results = topics.collect do |topic|
    Twitter.search(topic, :result_type => 'recent').results
  end
  search_results.flatten.each do |status|
    puts status.from_user
    Twitter.follow(status.from_user_id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at your code (I simplified it a little bit)

```
attr_accessible :client
def initialize 
  client = Twitter::Client.new
end
.... 
def searchAdd(topics)
  [*topics].each do |topic|                                        
    Twitter.search(topic, :result_type => "recent").each do |tweet| 
      client.follow :screen_name => tweet.from_user_id)
      # OR without client ↴
      # Twitter.post('friendships/create',:screen_name => tweet.from_user_id)
    end
  end
end
```

### What does it do ??

- Go through each topic
- search recent Topics
- follow users that match the topic I want

I am not familiar enough to know if friendships/create is the same as setting a user to follow but if it is that what it does.  I hope this helps

Dont for get to look in the api's for usage

- [twitter gem API](http://twitter.rubyforge.org/)
- [twitter gem Source](https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter/blob/master/lib/twitter/request.rb)

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's a lot cleaner but I'm running into the same issues. I don't think search and follow return attributes the way I think they do. and the twitter gem API is great but I need more examples of implementation ( I'm getting lost )